# Is there anywhere on Stack Exchange that offers a comprehensive list of code that serve as examples of good programming?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I know that [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a great place to get feedback on programs and examine code. But, I would love to see a place on Stack Exchange that keeps a comprehensive list of **complete** programs that are voted on by a number of characteristics such as readability, concept illustration, elegance, programming classics, etc.

Reading others' code and playing with it really helps me to understand new concepts. Does anyone think that is a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such context is specifically out of scope for SE. SE is a question-and-answers site; a place to get specific answers to specific questions. That falls outside of that scope.

Comment: I see your point.  However, you could probably make the same argument for code review.  The basic question is "how can I improve my code?".  The basic question for a programs repository might be "why is this program important?" thereby facilitating discussion.  I may be wrong but I definitely think it would be a valuable site on this network.

Comment: @MichaelJames If you think that you can come up with a suitable set of guidelines to demonstrate how such a site would be able to function properly within the SE framework, and succeed in building a community of people willing to commit to participating in it, then feel free to create the proposal on area51.  I wouldn't have high hopes though.

Comment: Ok.  I do see your point. Thank you very much for your input.